# How to get the square root of each number in an array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I looked all over but there doesn't seem to be any threads on this topic for C++. It does what it is supposed to but only for the first number in the array, how can I make it move along the array and take the square root of each number?

```
double doTheMath(double numbers[], const int SIZE, char choice)
{
double result = 0;

switch (toupper(choice))
{
case 'A': for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    result = sqrt(numbers [i]);
}
          return result;
       break;
//===============================================
//===============================================

void showResult(char choice, double result)
{
switch (toupper(choice))
{
case 'A': cout << "The square root of each number equals:\n " << result << endl;
    break;
```

Comment: How does this "do" anything if it does not compile?

Comment: this is just a small portion of my code

Comment: not sure why im getting downvoted

Comment: You are calculating the square root of all numbers it seems, but only using one variable to store them. I guess you need to use another array or reuse the same array.

Comment: where would I reuse the array? I see what you mean when you say im only using one variable to store them, so would i create result1,result2 etc?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is so far off the wall, I think the only appropriate thing to do is to submit a good solution for you to study:

```
void doAndPrintTheMath(const std::vector<double>& numbers){
    for (auto number : numbers){
        std::cout << ::sqrt(number) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Study each point in turn, and go from there.